# Does $x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{\,\,\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(60deg)}{\vdots}}}}}} =y$ imply $2=4$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, power-towers

**Edit:**

My question has been requested to close due to its apparent lack of clarity. My question is below under "**Problem**". If the information above it is redundant, please let me know in a comment. I will try my best to make my question as clear as possible.

---

I was looking at the equation $x^y=y$. If I want to isolate $x$, we would have $$x=y^{1/y}\stackrel{\small\rm{or}}{=}\sqrt[y]{y}.$$

Now let's consider $x^{x^y}=y$. I did not know how to do this, but I noticed something at first. If we let $x^y=y$, then this means $x^{x^y}=y\implies x^y=y$ by order of substitution. Notice that the same equation we substituted is in fact yielded; and, as mentioned previously, this equation would arrive at the fact that $x=y^{1/y}$. If we substitute *this* equation in, we obtain:

$$({y^{1/y}})^{(y^{1/y})^{y}}=y$$ which is clearly true.

But that means...

$$x^y=y\implies x^{x^y}=y\implies x^{x^{x^y}}=y\implies x^{x^{x^{x^y}}}=y\implies \cdots\tag1$$

It is now clear that we can look at this from a different perspective: if $x^y=y$ then similarly, $y=x^y$. We can substitute this on the LHS of the former equation, therefore resulting in that $x^{x^y}=y$. Clearly, this can be done ad infinitum, and this angle of looking at it is much easier to mentally grasp.

However.... if $x^y=y$ and $x^{x^y}=y$ then this means $x^y=x^{x^y}$ which doesn't make sense. Perhaps I am missing the part that $$x^y=x^{x^y}\color{red}{\iff x^y=y}$$ for otherwise we could let $x$ and $y$ be equal to anything, even each other, in the equation $x^y=x^{x^y}$ and quickly arrive at some problems.

---

**Problem:**

Now I have a problem when it comes to a certain substitution. If we can carry out the implications as shown in $(1)$ forever and ever, we will get the following equation:

> $$x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{\,\,\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(60deg)}{\vdots}}}}}} =y.\tag2$$

Considering that $\sqrt[4]{4}=\sqrt{\sqrt{4}}=\sqrt{2}$ then one can quickly deduce from *Eq.* $(2)$ that $2=4$ which is clearly wrong. Let $y=2$ then $x=\sqrt{2}$. Let $y=4$ then $x=\sqrt [4]{4}=\sqrt{2}$. Thus $2=4$.

But since we just discussed the entire concept of this equation and there doesn't seem to be any flaws with it, why am I getting the absurd flaw now that $2=4$? Clearly I did something wrong with the substitution, but that's the easy part, so I believe I am overlooking something, something likely obvious $-$ but I don't understand!

May someone please correct me on this? Any help would be much appreciated (particularly hints).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have $y=2\to x=\sqrt{2},$ and then you have $y=4\to x=\sqrt{2}.$ But if $A\to C$ and $B\to C,$ why is $A$ equivalent to $B?$ That would be like saying, "If you're a dog, then you're a mammal. If you're a cat, you're also a mammal. Therefore, if you're a dog, you're a cat." In logic, we call this the fallacy of the undistributed middle.

Comment: @PeterForeman  $a=-1$ and $b=2$, $c=0$

Comment: You are getting an absurd thing because any x and y won't fit in the equation . You can do that only on the solutions .

Comment: @AdrianKeister that is a very good point. Why did I not think of this earlier? Maybe I should go to bed... it is 4:23am for me right now xD

Comment: @PeterForeman Still fails if $a = 1$. It should work whenever $|a| \neq 1$.

Comment: @AdrianKeister I will delete my question now after a minute. Thanks for your input. I will work on this tomorrow so I can get some rest. In the meantime, you can have some reputation. Thanks for the help, intuitive as it may be! I also appreciate everyone else's efforts here :)

Comment: @MrPie: Thanks, have a good one!

Comment: Yesterday YouTube suggested me [this](https://youtu.be/DmP3sFIZ0XE) video. O haven't watched yet but I hope it helps you.

Comment: @Dog_69 thank you!! I did some research myself and came across [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UNwhaN2s2ww&t=409s) video. But the one you recommended to me is far better suited for this question, so again, thank you very much! :)

Comment: @Mr.Pie Fantastic. It's a pleasure for me to be able to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error mainly occurs in assuming that $y$ can be equal to $4$. It is known (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Infinite_heights)) that the infinite 'power-tower' only converges to values within the range $(e^{-1},e)$ for real $x$ (where $x$ is chosen such that the 'power-tower' converges) which does not include $4$.

Comment: Ha, I didn't know that! I was just about to delete this question in the thought that this was a ridiculous question merely wasting everyone's time; but now that there is an official answer, namely this one, I will refrain from doing that. I am also glad I learnt something, before I head off to bed. Unless there is another potentially better answer, you will earn the checkmark, sir! Thank you for your explanation! :)

Comment: I think the tower part isn't necessary to show the contradiction. Simply take $y=x^y$, and observe that $y=4, x=\sqrt{2}$ satisfies this. It's natural to assume that you can substitute to obtain $y=x^{x^y}$, but the aforementioned values of $x$ and $y$ no longer work. What exactly forbids this self-substitution?

Comment: @Vedvart1 The aforementioned values of $x,y$ still work. $4=(\sqrt{2})^{(\sqrt{2})^4}$

Comment: @PeterForeman No, they don't: $\sqrt{2}^{(\sqrt{2}^4)}=\sqrt{2}^2=2\not=4$.

Comment: @Vedvart1 Um, I am sorry to say that you are mistaken: $\sqrt{2}^4=2^{4/2}=2^2=4$.

Comment: @MrPie Wow, not sure what I was thinking here... nevermind. Thank you for spelling it out lol

Comment: @Vedvart1 Haha, it's called being human. Everyone makes mistakes, don't stress :)